# SQL to strSQL access

Tags: sql

So when I use the click and drag option of access to make my SQL I get something I don't understand and can't make it into a strSQL.

I need a solution for a school project, I don't have much time left

`SELECT tblklas.fldnaam AS Klas, tbllokaal.fldnummer AS Hoofdlokaal, tblvak.fldvak AS Vak, tbllokaal_1.fldnaam AS LesLokaal, tblleerkracht.fldnaam AS NaamLeerkrachtNormaal, tblleerkracht.fldvoornaam AS VoornaamLeerkrachtnormaal, tbldag.flddag AS Dag, tbllesuur.fldvan AS Van, tbllesuur.fldtot AS Tot
FROM (((tbllokaal AS tbllokaal_2 RIGHT JOIN (tblvervangingen LEFT JOIN tblleerkracht AS tblleerkracht_1 ON tblvervangingen.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht_1.fldleerkrachtID) ON tbllokaal_2.fldlokaalID = tblvervangingen.fldlokaalID) LEFT JOIN tbltaak ON tblvervangingen.fldtaakID = tbltaak.fldtaakID) LEFT JOIN tblleerkracht AS tblleerkracht_2 ON tbltaak.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht_2.fldleerkrachtID) RIGHT JOIN (((tbllokaal AS tbllokaal_1 INNER JOIN (((tbldag INNER JOIN (tblklas INNER JOIN tbluurroosterleerkracht ON tblklas.fldklasID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldklasID) ON tbldag.flddagID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.flddagID) INNER JOIN tblvak ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldvakID = tblvak.fldvakID) INNER JOIN tbllokaal ON tblklas.fldlokaalID = tbllokaal.fldlokaalID) ON tbllokaal_1.fldlokaalID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldlokaalID) INNER JOIN tbllesuur ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldlesuurID = tbllesuur.fldlesuurID) INNER JOIN tblleerkracht ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht.fldleerkrachtID) ON tblvervangingen.flduurroosterleerkrachtID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.flduurroosterleerkrachtID;`

Comment: What you can't type strSql = "" in your editor and paste this in between the Quotes? Also given you don't understand it, whats the point?

Comment: Normally I have very simple sql codes that I put into my visual basic as strSQL, but this one got '(' and I never learned how to work with that. I actually just need a strSQL from this.

Comment: The only "trick" to this is to make sure you have escape `"` and maintain spaces. E.g. `"SELECT a" & "FROM b"` will NOT work. `"SELECT a" & " FROM b"` will.

Comment: *Also given you don't understand it, whats the point?* All my +1s

Comment: Do you know what is strSQL in the first place? FYI it's just a normal String variable which stores your String, and in this case I guess you just want to store your SQL commands as a String. If you do not even know how to store a phrase/characters into a String variable for vb, go re-learn basic programming. You do not need to escape "(" nor ")" for vb String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying your query in my own Microsoft Visual Basic IDE. I guess I know what's the problem. Your question in stack overflow is wrong. You should ask "my query is too long to assign to a String variable in vb, how do I go about it?" instead. Well. Whatever but here you goes, Use & _ to write on the new next line

```
    strSQL = "SELECT tblklas.fldnaam AS Klas, tbllokaal.fldnummer AS Hoofdlokaal, tblvak.fldvak AS Vak, tbllokaal_1.fldnaam AS LesLokaal, tblleerkracht.fldnaam AS NaamLeerkrachtNormaal, tblleerkracht.fldvoornaam AS VoornaamLeerkrachtnormaal, tbldag.flddag AS Dag, tbllesuur.fldvan AS Van, tbllesuur.fldtot AS Tot " & _
"FROM (((tbllokaal AS tbllokaal_2 RIGHT JOIN (tblvervangingen LEFT JOIN tblleerkracht AS tblleerkracht_1 ON tblvervangingen.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht_1.fldleerkrachtID) ON tbllokaal_2.fldlokaalID = tblvervangingen.fldlokaalID) LEFT JOIN tbltaak ON tblvervangingen.fldtaakID = tbltaak.fldtaakID) " & _
"LEFT JOIN tblleerkracht AS tblleerkracht_2 ON tbltaak.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht_2.fldleerkrachtID) RIGHT JOIN (((tbllokaal AS tbllokaal_1 INNER JOIN (((tbldag INNER JOIN (tblklas INNER JOIN tbluurroosterleerkracht ON tblklas.fldklasID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldklasID) ON tbldag.flddagID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.flddagID) " & _
"INNER JOIN tblvak ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldvakID = tblvak.fldvakID) INNER JOIN tbllokaal ON tblklas.fldlokaalID = tbllokaal.fldlokaalID) ON tbllokaal_1.fldlokaalID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldlokaalID) INNER JOIN tbllesuur ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldlesuurID = tbllesuur.fldlesuurID) " & _
"INNER JOIN tblleerkracht ON tbluurroosterleerkracht.fldleerkrachtID = tblleerkracht.fldleerkrachtID) ON tblvervangingen.flduurroosterleerkrachtID = tbluurroosterleerkracht.flduurroosterleerkrachtID"
```